# Have difficulty/difficulties (in) doing something

Tags: prepositional-phrases, present-participles, omissibility

What is syntactically the -*ing*-phrase in both the versions with and without the preposition? For example in *He has trouble [in] keeping things in perspective right now*.

Secondly, does the latter derive form the former?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference. The omission of prepositions in modifying phrases is and has been common in English:

He lived there [for] several years.

Kiplng L 108 I shall always be threepence short in my accounts = I shall always be short in my accounts **by** threepence

Gissing G 197 she blames herself no end = she blames herself **without** an end.

Darwin L 1.209 I can hardly think there will be a coronation [at] this time [in] fifty years.

Thus we have

**keeping things** - gerund phrase acting adjectivally

**in keeping things** - Adjectival prepositional modifier (in + gerund phrase.)

*Examples taken from "A Modern English Grammar on Historical Principles Part7 Syntax V4 1949 by O Jespersen.*

Comment: What would those "adjectives" modify?

Comment: Their noun.....

Comment: What noun? I genuinely do not understand it, the example was _He has trouble [in] keeping things in perspective right now_

Comment: He has ***trouble*** *[in] keeping things in perspective* right now. The noun is trouble.